# Do you need to have images be at 3x size in my Cloud Storage for iOS?

Tags: swift, firebase

I am loading images into my app from Firebase Storage and want them to have the highest resolution possible without loading a massive file size. In my app, I am displaying each image at 100x500. In Firebase storage should these be set to 300x1500 (3x the pixels they will be shown at) or does that not matter and saving them at 100x500 will have the same resolution as 300x1500?

Comment: This question is super vague. *the same result*... the same result as what? A 100x500 image has less data and resolution than a 300x1500 image which is different than a 100x500 image. If you're loading them into a 32x32 imageView it won't make any difference. If it's just a thumbnail, wont make a difference there either. So. What are you asking? What's the use case? How are you using the image?

Comment: @Jay thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question with some more specifics.

Comment: Please clarify what *massive file size* is - for me a raw image file is *massive* but a 10Mb file isn't. Also, Storage is just storage - it can store whatever you put in it so there's no 'best way'. You can have a Firebase function resize the image for you with [Image Transformation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation) or you can do it yourself, or not at all. A 100x500 image is lower resolution than a 300x1500 image so it can't be 'the same resolution'

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test on my iPhone with 100x500, 300x1500, and then the max (same aspect ratio). The 100x500 was blurry and the 300x1500 and max both looked identical. Based on this, I'd say you do need to have the images as 3x size